# Fetching multiple coordinates from database for Google Maps using CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, google-maps-api-3

i am trying to get multiple latitude and longitude values from database and plot a google map. i have around 460 different locations in my database with their name, latitude and longitude values. I need markers for all of those values at once when the map is loaded. All 460 markers should be displayed at once and when the user clicks on the marker, infomap about that place should be displayed by fetching values from database. i am using codeigniter to do this task and i do not understand how to fetch the values in model, pass it through contorller and how to display it in view.

Comment: Have you read the CodeIgniter documentation? It's some of the best online documentation of a framework I've ever witnessed online. The explanation of how Models, Views and Controllers interact is extensively covered [Start here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html)

Answer (score 1):

I've created a library specifically for integrating Google Maps into CodeIgniter which would do exactly as what you require. You can find documentation and demonstrations at the below URL:

http://biostall.com/codeigniter-google-maps-v3-api-library

Let me know if you need any help using it :)

Cheers